# How to configure custom servlet in Jruby-rack?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, servlets, jruby, jruby-rack

According to [Jruby-Rack Github](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack), we can configure to use org.jruby.rack.RackServlet instead of context listener.

Can we use another custom servlet rather than RackServlet? Or can we override org.jruby.rack.RackServlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener stays - you usually use a servlet instead of a filter with the Servlet API e.g.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>rack</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.jruby.rack.RackFilter</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>rack</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- using the above servlet instead of : -->
<!--
<filter>
  <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.jruby.rack.RackFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
-->

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can override the `RackFilter` as well as the `RackServlet` you can even use a custom class as long as it plays by JRuby-Rack's rules. With the latest Trinidad (uses JRuby-Rack under the hood) it's a bit easier to configure an alternate servlet without writing a *web.xml* e.g. in *config/trinidad.yml* you might :

```
---
  address: localhost
  port: 3000  # port where Trinidad is running
  rack_servlet:
    class: org.blue-smith.rack.CoolRackServlet
```

If you do make sure your `CoolRackServlet` class is on the class-path e.g. package it in a jar and put the .jar under *[APP_ROOT]/lib/java* or for quick testing simply copy the compiled .class file(s) including the package directories under *lib/java/classes* ...